# Formatting a hardcoded json object in TypeScript with jagged array

Tags: angular, typescript

Im probably being dumb here, but I dont understand why

```
  productSpecificStyling: any;

  this.productSpecificStyling = {
      headerDividerStyle: { height: "5px"},
      buttonNext: { color: "purple"},
      buttonPrevious: { color: "yellow" }
  };
```

works fine, but

```
  productSpecificStyling: any;

  this.productSpecificStyling = {
      headerDividerStyle: { height: "5px",width:"100px"},
      buttonNext: { color: "purple"},
      buttonPrevious: { color: "yellow" }
  };
```

raises an error complaining that theres a : expected.

Edit: Sorry guys, I had been experimenting when I pasted this, I guess its something to do with the - in background-color

```
  productSpecificStyling: any;

  this.productSpecificStyling = {
      headerDividerStyle: { height: "5px",background-color:"red"},
      buttonNext: { color: "purple"},
      buttonPrevious: { color: "yellow" }
  };
```

Comment: I have tried the same in my IDE and don't get any such error.  Do you have a more complete sample?  Also, is this the exact code causing the issue? (i.e. did you copy paste it)

Comment: You are correct, I created this specific example to illustrate, but its not exactly the error - sorry guys.  the error is when the "width" is changed to "background-color" - I had been experimenting before hand - I guess its something to do with the hypen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maloric pointed the way. the hypen is not valid in a JSON Property, but I have to create it anyway!. enclosing it in [""] made it work. e.g.

```
 this.productSpecificStyling = {
      headerDividerStyle: { height: "5px",["background-color"]:"red"},
      buttonNext: { color: "purple"},
      buttonPrevious: { color: "yellow" }
  };
```

Comment: You actually don't need the square brackets around "background-color" - the quotes should be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

productSpecificStyling: any;

this.productSpecificStyling = { headerDividerStyle: [{ height: "5px",width:"100px"}], buttonNext: { color: "purple"}, buttonPrevious: { color: "yellow" } };

Add array to headerDividerStyle... should work fine

Comment: Not sure I understand your logic here.  There is no need for an array, and it changes the type of headerDividerStyle.  Only use an array if you expect there to be multiple items.